re-order columns based on values inside dataframe in certain order which is row-wise descending
This question is not related to sorting using column names alphabetically, the problem statement is re-order columns based on values inside dataframe in certain order which is row-wise decending
I have below dataframe,
JSWINFRA    GUFICBIO        HARIOMPIPE  
3           4               4           
1           3               3           
0           0               1           
4           1               0

I want it to be sorted like below,
Note: I can't use df.sort_values(by='column_name') as columns are generated dynamically from API
HARIOMPIPE  GUFICBIO        JSWINFRA    
4           4               3           
3           3               1           
1           0               0           
0           1               4

How can I do it via pandas ?

You can get the sorted order of the columns with np.lexsort and reorder with iloc:
df.iloc[:,np.lexsort(-df.to_numpy()[::-1])]

Output:
   HARIOMPIPE  GUFICBIO  JSWINFRA
0           4         4         3
1           3         3         1
2           1         0         0
3           0         1         `

Intermediate:
np.lexsort(-df.to_numpy()[::-1])
# array([2, 1, 0])

